# Randomize Optimal Action Choice

Tags: python-2.7, q-learning

I'm working on the code below for a self driving car program.  I have an issue in my choose_action function.  The agent should be choosing a random action from a choice of actions that have the highest Q-value in the step below:

"else:
                action = maxQaction"

But the way I have it written now it will just choose the same action everytime.  Can anyone suggest how to randomize the selection for the highest Q-value, maybe I could use a list.

```
Code:
import random
import math
from environment import Agent, Environment
from planner import RoutePlanner
from simulator import Simulator
import itertools

class LearningAgent(Agent):
    """ An agent that learns to drive in the Smartcab world.
        This is the object you will be modifying. """ 

    def __init__(self, env, learning=False, epsilon=1.0, alpha=0.5):
        super(LearningAgent, self).__init__(env)     # Set the agent in the evironment 
        self.planner = RoutePlanner(self.env, self)  # Create a route planner
        self.valid_actions = self.env.valid_actions  # The set of valid actions

        # Set parameters of the learning agent
        self.learning = learning # Whether the agent is expected to learn
        self.Q = dict()          # Create a Q-table which will be a dictionary of tuples
        self.epsilon = epsilon   # Random exploration factor
        self.alpha = alpha       # Learning factor

        ###########
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # Set any additional class parameters as needed

        self.states = [            
            ['red', 'green'],                   #light
            ['left', 'right', 'forward', None], #vehicleleft
            ['left', 'right', 'forward', None], #vehicleright
            ['left', 'right', 'forward', None],  #vehicleoncoming
            ['left', 'right', 'forward']       #waypoint
        ]

        self.x = 0
        random.seed(42)

        self.q_maker = dict((k, 0.0) for k in self.valid_actions)

        for prod_state in itertools.product(*self.states):
            self.Q[prod_state] = self.q_maker.copy()



    def reset(self, destination=None, testing=False):
        """ The reset function is called at the beginning of each trial.
            'testing' is set to True if testing trials are being used
            once training trials have completed. """

        # Select the destination as the new location to route to
        self.planner.route_to(destination)

        ########### 
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # Update epsilon using a decay function of your choice
        # Update additional class parameters as needed
        # If 'testing' is True, set epsilon and alpha to 0

        #Added for Question 6
        #self.x = self.x + 1
        if testing:
            self.epsilon = 0.0
            self.alpha = 0.0
        else:
            #self.epsilon = self.epsilon - 0.05 for question 6

            self.x += 1
            self.epsilon = math.exp(-self.alpha*self.x)
            #self.epsilon = math.fabs(math.cos(self.alpha*self.x))
            # self.epsilon = 1.0/(self.x**2)
            # self.epsilon = self.alpha**self.x


        return None

    def build_state(self):
        """ The build_state function is called when the agent requests data from the 
            environment. The next waypoint, the intersection inputs, and the deadline 
            are all features available to the agent. """

        # Collect data about the environment
        waypoint = self.planner.next_waypoint() # The next waypoint 
        inputs = self.env.sense(self)           # Visual input - intersection light and traffic
        deadline = self.env.get_deadline(self)  # Remaining deadline

        ########### 
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # Set 'state' as a tuple of relevant data for the agent        
        #state = (waypoint, inputs['light'], inputs['left'], inputs['right'], inputs['oncoming']) #None modified for "Update the Driving Agent State"

        state = (inputs['light'], inputs['left'], inputs['right'], inputs['oncoming'],waypoint) 

        return state


    def get_maxQ(self, state):
        """ The get_max_Q function is called when the agent is asked to find the
            maximum Q-value of all actions based on the 'state' the smartcab is in. """

        ########### 
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # Calculate the maximum Q-value of all actions for a given state


        action_selections = self.Q[state]

        maxQ = max(action_selections.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1]

        return maxQ 



    def createQ(self, state):
        """ The createQ function is called when a state is generated by the agent. """

        ########### 
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # When learning, check if the 'state' is not in the Q-table
        # If it is not, create a new dictionary for that state
        #   Then, for each action available, set the initial Q-value to 0.0

        if not self.learning:
            return

        if not state in self.Q:
            self.Q[state] = self.q_maker.copy()

        return


    def choose_action(self, state):
        """ The choose_action function is called when the agent is asked to choose
            which action to take, based on the 'state' the smartcab is in. """

        # Set the agent state and default action
        self.state = state
        self.next_waypoint = self.planner.next_waypoint()
        action = random.choice([None, 'forward', 'left', 'right']) ##None ##Modified from None for question 3
        #action = None  # added after first submission

        ########### 
        ## TO DO ##
        ###########
        # When not learning, choose a random action
        # When learning, choose a random action with 'epsilon' probability
        #   Otherwise, choose an action with the highest Q-value for the current state



        action_selections = self.Q[state]
        maxQaction = max(action_selections.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
        if self.learning:
            choose_using_epsilon  = random.random() < 1 - self.epsilon
            if not choose_using_epsilon:
                valid_actions = filter(lambda x: x != maxQaction, 
                    Environment.valid_actions)
                action = random.choice(valid_actions)
            else:
                action = maxQaction
        else:
            action = random.choice(Environment.valid_actions)
        return action
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if not self.learning or random.random() < self.epsilon:
            action = random.choice(self.valid_actions)
        else:
            maxQaction= self.get_maxQ(state)
            maxQaction= [] # build list of actions that match the max Q value
            for act in self.Q[state]:
                if self.Q[state][act] == maxQ:
                    maxQaction.append(act)
            action = random.choice(maxQaction) # choose one randomly
```